# Free full version anti-virus software?

Tags: gratis, antivirus

Is there any genuinely free full version anti-virus software for PC? This is impossible to google because you will always get directed to free trials and limited versions. Is there any genuinely free and genuinely useful anti-virus software? Like open source stuff that people made just for the sake of being helpful?

Comment: For what purpose? Windows (10 and 11) already contains a good Anti Virus named Defender.

Comment: For what operating system?